# TSQL - Create view based on table rows and cell values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, cursor

I'm stuck with below left table structure (SQL Server 2012) to create a view or function that will output the right table in the screenshot:

[image: Input and Output]

The **TestOutput** table contains data starting with **RowNumber 10** (Step0_Name1) for every **ID**. In the real scenario there are more steps than I listed here as an example.

I'm hoping for some logic to get all pairs written lke **Step0_Name1** and **Step0_Name1_Status** be it by name/number recognition or row numbering.

I'm guessing cursors will be needed to create some kind of loop logic.

Unfortunately sqlfiddle.com throws an error so I pasted the schema in here:

Create Test:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test](
    [ID] [nchar](5) NOT NULL,
    [Version] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [RowNumber] [int] NOT NULL,
    [COLUMN1] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [COLUMN2] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [COLUMN3] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [COLUMN4] [numeric](15, 3) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Test] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(   [ID] ASC,
    [RowNumber] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Insert Test:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test]
           ([ID] ,[Version] ,[RowNumber],[COLUMN1],[COLUMN2],[COLUMN3],[COLUMN4])
Values 
('00010',1, 1, 'Sheet', 'Part',             'A',            NULL),
('00010',1, 2, 'Sheet', 'Name',             'PartName',     NULL),
('00010',1, 3, 'Sheet', 'Price',            NULL,           1.470),
('00010',1, 4, 'Sheet', 'Step0_SOP',        '2015 CW 09',   NULL),
('00010',1, 5, 'Sheet', 'Step1_SOP',        '2015 CW 10',   NULL),
('00010',1, 6, 'Sheet', 'Step2_SOP',        '2015 CW 11',   NULL),
('00010',1, 7, 'Sheet', 'Step0_Status',     'pending',      NULL),
('00010',1, 8, 'Sheet', 'Step1_Status',     'frozen',       NULL),
('00010',1, 9, 'Sheet', 'Step2_Status',     'released',     NULL),
('00010',1, 10,'Sheet', 'Step0_Name1',      'Auser',        NULL),
('00010',1, 11,'Sheet', 'Step0_Name2',       NULL,          NULL),
('00010',1, 12,'Sheet', 'Step0_Name3',      'Buser',        NULL),
('00010',1, 13,'Sheet', 'Step0_Name1_Status','started',     NULL),
('00010',1, 14,'Sheet', 'Step0_Name2_Status',NULL,          NULL),
('00010',1, 15,'Sheet', 'Step0_Name3_Status','pending',     NULL),
('00010',1, 16,'Sheet', 'Step1_Name1',      'Wuser',        NULL),
('00010',1, 17,'Sheet', 'Step1_Name2',      'Cuser',        NULL),
('00010',1, 18,'Sheet', 'Step1_Name3',      'Duser',        NULL),
('00010',1, 19,'Sheet', 'Step1_Name1_Status','released',    NULL),
('00010',1, 20,'Sheet', 'Step1_Name2_Status','pending',     NULL),
('00010',1, 21,'Sheet', 'Step1_Name3_Status','released',    NULL),

('00020',1, 1, 'Sheet', 'Part',             'B',            NULL),
('00020',1, 2, 'Sheet', 'Name',             'PartName',     NULL),
('00020',1, 3, 'Sheet', 'Price',            NULL,           2.190),
('00020',1, 4, 'Sheet', 'Step0_SOP',        '2016 CW 19',   NULL),
('00020',1, 5, 'Sheet', 'Step1_SOP',        '2016 CW 20',   NULL),
('00020',1, 6, 'Sheet', 'Step2_SOP',        '2015 CW 21',   NULL),
('00020',1, 7, 'Sheet', 'Step0_Status',     'released',     NULL),
('00020',1, 8, 'Sheet', 'Step1_Status',     'frozen',       NULL),
('00020',1, 9, 'Sheet', 'Step2_Status',     'pending',      NULL),
('00020',1, 10,'Sheet', 'Step0_Name1',      'Xuser',        NULL),
('00020',1, 11,'Sheet', 'Step0_Name2',       NULL,          NULL),
('00020',1, 12,'Sheet', 'Step0_Name3',      'Wuser',        NULL),
('00020',1, 13,'Sheet', 'Step0_Name1_Status','started',     NULL),
('00020',1, 14,'Sheet', 'Step0_Name2_Status',NULL,          NULL),
('00020',1, 15,'Sheet', 'Step0_Name3_Status','pending',     NULL),
('00020',1, 16,'Sheet', 'Step1_Name1',      'Auser',        NULL),
('00020',1, 17,'Sheet', 'Step1_Name2',      'Cuser',        NULL),
('00020',1, 18,'Sheet', 'Step1_Name3',      'Buser',        NULL),
('00020',1, 19,'Sheet', 'Step1_Name1_Status','frozen',      NULL),
('00020',1, 20,'Sheet', 'Step1_Name2_Status','pending',     NULL),
('00020',1, 21,'Sheet', 'Step1_Name3_Status','released',    NULL)
```

Create TestOutput:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestOutput](
    [ID] [nchar](5) NOT NULL,
    [StepCount] [int] NULL
    [StepNo] [int] NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Status] [nvarchar](max) NULL   
    )
```

Insert TestOutput:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestOutput]   ([ID] ,[StepCount] ,[StepNo],[Name],[Status])
Values 
('00010',1, 0, 'Auser', 'started'),
('00010',2, 0, NULL, NULL),
('00010',3, 0, 'Buser', 'pending'),
('00010',1, 1, 'Wuser', 'released'),
('00010',2, 1, 'Cuser', 'pending'),
('00010',3, 1, 'Duser', 'released'),

('00020',1, 0, 'Xuser', 'started'),
('00020',2, 0, NULL, NULL),
('00020',3, 0, 'Wuser', 'pending'),
('00020',1, 1, 'Auser', 'frozen'),
('00020',2, 1, 'Cuser', 'pending'),
('00020',3, 1, 'Buser', 'released')
```

I hope you can show me a way how this could be solved.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for cursor.

You could first get `StepNo`, then calculate `StepCount` using windowed function and join results:

```
SELECT s1.ID,
       s1.StepCount,
       s1.StepNo,
       [Name]     = s1.Column3,
       [Status]   = s2.Column3 
FROM (SELECT *,
        [StepCount] =  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, StepNo ORDER BY RowNumber)
      FROM (SELECT *, 
               [StepNo] = SUBSTRING(Column2, 5, CHARINDEX('_', Column2)-5)
            FROM Test
            WHERE Column2 LIKE 'Step%_Name%' 
              AND Column2 NOT LIKE '%Status') AS sub) AS s1
JOIN (SELECT *, 
        [StepCount] =  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, StepNo ORDER BY RowNumber)
      FROM (SELECT *, 
             [StepNo] = SUBSTRING(Column2, 5, CHARINDEX('_', Column2)-5)
            FROM Test
            WHERE Column2 LIKE 'Step%_Name%_Status') AS sub) AS s2
  ON s1.ID = s2.ID
 AND s1.StepCount = s2.StepCount
 AND s1.StepNo = s2.StepNo
ORDER BY ID, StepNo, StepCount;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/443285)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═══════╦═══════════╦════════╦═══════╦══════════╗
║  ID   ║ StepCount ║ StepNo ║ Name  ║  Status  ║
╠═══════╬═══════════╬════════╬═══════╬══════════╣
║ 00010 ║         1 ║      0 ║ Auser ║ started  ║
║ 00010 ║         2 ║      0 ║       ║          ║
║ 00010 ║         3 ║      0 ║ Buser ║ pending  ║
║ 00010 ║         1 ║      1 ║ Wuser ║ released ║
║ 00010 ║         2 ║      1 ║ Cuser ║ pending  ║
║ 00010 ║         3 ║      1 ║ Duser ║ released ║
║ 00020 ║         1 ║      0 ║ Xuser ║ started  ║
║ 00020 ║         2 ║      0 ║       ║          ║
║ 00020 ║         3 ║      0 ║ Wuser ║ pending  ║
║ 00020 ║         1 ║      1 ║ Auser ║ frozen   ║
║ 00020 ║         2 ║      1 ║ Cuser ║ pending  ║
║ 00020 ║         3 ║      1 ║ Buser ║ released ║
╚═══════╩═══════════╩════════╩═══════╩══════════╝
```

---

The same with CTE:

```
;WITH cte_name AS
(
  SELECT *,
        [StepCount] =  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, StepNo ORDER BY RowNumber)
  FROM (SELECT *, 
          [StepNo] = SUBSTRING(Column2, 5, CHARINDEX('_', Column2)-5)
       FROM #Test
       WHERE Column2 LIKE 'Step%_Name%' 
         AND Column2 NOT LIKE '%Status') AS sub
), cte_status AS
(
  SELECT *, 
        [StepCount] =  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, StepNo ORDER BY RowNumber)
  FROM (SELECT *, 
             [StepNo] = SUBSTRING(Column2, 5, CHARINDEX('_', Column2)-5)
        FROM #Test
        WHERE Column2 LIKE 'Step%_Name%_Status') AS sub
)
SELECT s1.ID,
       s1.StepCount,
       s1.StepNo,
       [Name]     = s1.Column3,
       [Status]   = s2.Column3 
FROM cte_name s1
JOIN cte_status s2
  ON s1.ID = s2.ID
 AND s1.StepCount = s2.StepCount
 AND s1.StepNo = s2.StepNo
ORDER BY ID, StepNo, StepCount;
```

Comment: fantastic. This is much faster than my case when statements before :-) Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select
  t.id
  ,row_number() over(
     partition by t.id,
                  substring(t.column2, 1, charindex('_', t.column2))
     order by t.column2
  ) StepCount
  ,substring(t.column2, 5, charindex('_', t.column2) - 5) [StepNo]
  ,t.column3 [Name]
  ,(
    select
      t1.column3
    from
      @test t1
    where
      t.column2 + '_Status' = t1.column2
      and t1.id = t.id
  ) [Status]
from
  @test t
where
  t.column2 like 'step[0-9]_name[0-9]'
;
```